# Does anyone know how to fix Puppet pdk error?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet, pdk

```
[✔] Running puppet validators ...
├── [✔] Checking Puppet manifest syntax (**/*.pp).
└── [✔] Checking Puppet manifest style (**/*.pp).
✖] Running ruby validators ...
└── [✖] Checking Ruby code style (**/**.rb).
Pdk validate fails
```

**Pdk validate fails**

Comment: You need to add the invalid Ruby code to the question.

Comment: ... or at least the diagnostics describing the code style violations.

Answer (score 0):

Run your command with "-d" option which is debug so that it will show what errors we are able to see in ruby validator.

> pdk validate -d